# Reconstitute all purpose wheat flour from starch and gluten

Tags: substitutions, flour, wheat, starch, vital-wheat-gluten

Due to the recent events (COVID-19) the groceries stores' shelves are totally wiped of flour of any grains. I have not found flour for roughly a week. Now the shelves are still stocked well with starches (corn and potato) and gluten flour/powder. Does anyone have experience with mixing both flours to acquire a flour that has roughly the same properties like plain all purpose wheat flour? AP flour has roughly 10% protein and 90% non-sugar carbohydrates. I am not sure if the 10% protein are 100% gluten and if corn starch or potato starch have roughly the same properties like wheat starch.

I intend to make simple yeast dough with improvised fillings with no special ratios (garlic bread, cinnamon rolls) or a flour-water dough for dumplings or pancakes (e.g. [scallion pancakes](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/04/extra-flaky-scallion-pancakes-recipe.html) or just normal crepes ), so nothing fancy. I do still have normal AP flour but I'd like to save it for more delicate doughs.

Milling own flour from semolina, couscous, bulgur, whole grains is not an option; I do not have a mill.

Comment: If nobody has an idea, I may just try it. Social distancing means more time for cooking :o)

Comment: You are not going to be able to produce wheat flour from those parts, but you might consider looking up recipes for gluten free "flour" mixes.

Comment: wheat starch exists, but it's hard to find outside of Asia and Australia

Comment: granted that it's not an option for you:  but wheat can be ground into flour in many small batches in an electric coffee/spice grinder.  it'll need to be sifted to regrind bigger bits and discard any chaff

Comment: Gluten makes up about 75-80% of the protein content of flour, but I agree with @moscafj, you won't get anything resembling wheat flour from that mixture.

Comment: @moscafj Thank you for the pointers! Looks like gluten free mixes consist of two thirds rice starch, some tapioka starch, and some potato/corn starch + binders (xanthan gum, pectin). In my case I can use gluten instead of the non-gluten binders.